# Using image and controls in front

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to use image and control in front I.e. taking existent image as background and put on it button ,list view etc.
I'm having blend 2012 and I try with adding grid and on it put image control and bind it to the image but its not working
since you cannot drag control to image,what is the right way to do it?

1. which image format is preferred in WPF (to support high quality image) ,is it bitmap ,gif ,jpg ?

Thanks,

Comment: '*you cannot drag control to image*'... try writing some XAML. '*which image format is preferred in WPF*'... the same as any other language... .png for graphics and .jpg for photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageSource" UriSource="dashboard.jpg"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey= ImageSource}" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid.Background>        
</Grid>
```

similarly you can use for Button and listbox background also.and if your image look blurry u can take help from here [My images are blurry! Why isn't WPF's SnapsToDevicePixels working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592017/my-images-are-blurry-why-isnt-wpfs-snapstodevicepixels-working)