# Only resize large images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resize, scaling

I've got a bunch of (very) large images in my application. For them to fit into my ImageView and the corresponding Image control, I'm using the following XAML:

```
<Image Name="imageEdit" Stretch="Uniform" />
```

Now this works marvelously when using large images, as they're automatically scaled down. However, when displaying small images they're being scaled higher and thus become blurry.

Is there a way I can prevent that from happening and only have those images resizes, that would otherwise actually reach behind the boundaries of the Image control?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In WPF there is a property just for this reason called `StretchDirection`, setting it to `DownOnly` does exactly what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the image size (dimensions) to the `Stretch` property through a converter.

Then in the converter return `Stretch.None` if the image size is less than or equal to the space available and `Stretch.Uniform` if it's larger. For example (just checking the X dimension):

```
public class SizeToStretchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value <= targetWidth ? Stretch.None : Stretch.Uniform;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may want to try setting [BitmapScalingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592017/my-images-are-blurry-why-isnt-wpfs-snapstodevicepixels-working) discussing blurry WPF images.