# WPF: Loaded images, in particular Ellipses, have low quality shape edge. How do I improve that?

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, ellipse

In a project I've loaded some images. However, in particular, Ellipses look quite ugly. As though an edge of ellipse shape is greatly indented. I know this is common issue for ellipsoid shapes.

So is there a way to improve edges?

Comment: If its an Image (jpg, png, bmp etc) the quality of the Image is retained in WPF (unless you are scaling up/down). So check if the actual image is crappy.

Comment: That's the point, in a pic viewer they look not so crappy as in WPF app!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including at least 3 sample images.

Comment: Yeah - please share image related code and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions

- Check the DPI of your image files. The default is often 72, whereas WPF works best with DPI = 96, otherwise it will try to scale the image.
- Set the RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode of your image control - see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734431/967885.

If you want really smooth curves though, ditch the bitmaps and use a WPF Geometry (e.g. Path) instead.

Comment: The pics were created with a standard DPI =96. OK, thanks for an advice. I'll try to follow. About "paths" you are right, "paths" images look much better. I knew it.