# Why does text quality get worse when I run my visual studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created a simple Winforms application in C#. When I run the application, the quality of text gets worse as shown in the picture below.
I'm working on CORELDRAW control addon project where the result of execution is a button inside the coreldraw program .
any help please ?

Before running:

[image: before running]

After running:

[image: after running]

Here is an animated back-and-forth comparison of a region of the two images.
[image: Animated comparison]

here is my project :

[super-design](https://github.com/AloushA/super-design)

Comment: It's a Windows Forms project?

Comment: What dpi and percentage scaling is your screen?

Comment: It seems that the screen ratio for app has changed and that width is smaller then it was before.

Comment: I'm assuming that the _"Super Design"_ item is a bitmap.  That looks like a bitmap scaling issue, and not really a "resolution" issue

Comment: it's a windows form but in a CORELDRAW control addon project .

Comment: The text has changed quality too.  There is no clear-type on "Apply" and "Add".  There is no anti-aliasing of the text of "Super Design" (it is rendered with only full-orange and full-white pixels, compared to smooth anti-aliased text with in-between shades.)

Comment: my dpi is 100% and my percentage scaling is 768 * 1366 @ThomasWeller

Comment: It's the "quality" of the text that is affected, not the "resolution".

Comment: Does that CorelDraw control have an "Antialias" or "Quality" property?

Comment: Curious to know if [BitmapScalingMode UseLayoutRounding or SnapsToDevicePixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592017/my-images-are-blurry-why-isnt-wpfs-snapstodevicepixels-working) are affecting it.

Comment: how could i know ? @ThomasWeller

Comment: Well, you are a programmer. You drag'n' drop the control onto the form and open the property window of it. Like with any other control.

Comment: It's suspicious that it looks correct in the _designer_ but not at runtime. Clearly the designer has the ability to render it with the correct quality settings.  My ability to reproduce this issue is greatly limited because it seems to be specific to your CORELDRAW control (which I don't have access to).

Comment: there is no a component called CORELDRAW control , however the result of execution is a control button inside the coreldraw program @ThomasWeller

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to add / render the control?